# Bootstrap 3 form inside modal not submitting on touch screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

This is starting to look like a Bootstrap bug, but I can't find any information about it...

I have the following Bootstrap modal with a form inside:

```
<div id="comment-delete-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"
    tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete comments</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete all selected comments?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form method="post" action="/delete">
          <input type="hidden" id="delete-comment-ids" name="delete-comment-ids" value="1,2,3" />
          <input type="hidden" name="entry-id" value="1" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes, delete comment(s)</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

This works great on Chrome on my PC or Mac.  On Chrome in my phone, however, when clicking the form submit button, the form is not actually getting submitted.  I noticed that on touch screens, clicking anywhere on the modal dismisses the modal - not just the Cancel button which is the expected behavior.

I tried the modal demo on Bootstrap's website from my touch screen using Chrome with the same result - touching anywhere within the modal dismisses it.  Buggy modal, buggy mobile browser, or am I missing something?

UPDATE: Works correctly in Dolphin browser, just not Chrome.